# Which characters do Threads of Fate plot rule apply to?

Tags: tragedy-looper

The Threads of Fate plot rule states

> [Loop Start] Place 2 Paranoia on all characters who had Goodwill last
>   loop

The spreading incident allows for Goodwill to be moved from a character to another character. So my question is, does this plot rule apply to characters who had Goodwill **at any time** or just characters who **ended** the loop with Goodwill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on rulings from Simon Lundström (who translated the rules), as stated [here](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/17970977#17970977):

> The subplot says (or should say) "characters who had at least one goodwill at the end of the previous loop".

So only the characters ([including corpses](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/18016478#18016478)) who had a Goodwill counter on them at the end of the loop get 2 Paranoia on them at the start of the next.